# How do I get my SharePoint 2010 Management Shell to open to PS C:\> instead of PS U:\>?

Tags: 2010, powershell, sharepoint-server

Whenever I open my SharePoint 2010 Management Shell on my remote desktop, it opens to `PS U:\>` rather than `PS C:\>` as it does on my coworker's machine. ![PS_U][1]

How do I get it to automatically open into `PS C:\>` ? ![PS_C][2]

Thank you!

U Drive:
![U Drive][3]

Update:
![U drive after steps][4]

(images removed)

Comment: are you using remote powershell?

Comment: I do remote into this server.

Comment: do one thing, if you change the map drive latter from U to something else S or T ? i think this will change it to new drive letter... test and let me know.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  Can you direct?  Thanks.

Comment: you have to dissconect then you have to map the network drive again.

Comment: But one thing is sure, you can not change powershell from u to c as you are using the Remote console not the local. If you install Powershell on your local machine then the drive letter will be c.

Comment: That's wrong.  My coworker remotes into the server.  Her powershell starts up with c.

Comment: What is his mapping? Either he is loading from his own machine  (which is my feeling) or his mapped drive letter is c. Can you install powershell on your pc?

Comment: What do you mean by mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://khalidansari.com/2014/04/07/change-sharepoint-management-shell-default-folder/

You need to modify the Target field, not the Start in field.  This is a pretty good blog on how to do this.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

go to the folder “ `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration`” and edit “`SharePoint.ps1”` file. Find the following line:

1. `Set-location $home`
   and replace `$home` with your folder:
2. Set-location `"c:\"`

[Change default location of Sharepoint management console](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2011/04/change-default-location-of-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Thank you Waqas.  I can get to Microsoft Shared, but I don't have the Web Server Extensions folder.  Any thoughts?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: is sharepoint installed on that server? is c is your system drive? or if U is your system drive then go fromt heir.

Comment: I'm not sure what my system drive is, my coworker's management shell comes up with c automatically, and we have the same settings.

Comment: can you see the folder path on U drive / c drive  / anyother drive>??

Comment: Is this what you mean?  (see original)  Thanks!

Comment: when you go to Mycomputer what drives are you seeing....is U is mapp drived?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why this is happening but I can provide a work around to stop it happening.

Open your management shell and type $profile and press enter.
A path will be shown.
If the file / path does not exist create it.
Open the file microsoft.powershell_profile.ps1 in a text editor
In the document enter "sl c:\" without the quotes and save the document
Close the management shell
When you open it your location will be set to c:\

You might be interested to know that you can add lots of commands to this profile that will run when PowerShell is launched.

Comment: Thank you, but no cigarillo.  I did have to create the path and the file that you specified.  I typed in that text and nothing else.  I logged off and back on, and it's still pulling the U: drive.  Sad Friday...  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Your issue is a little perplexing, When I am back in the office tomorrow I am going to try and replicate it. In the mean time you can check to see if the profile is being loaded by adding this line to it .

Write-Host "I am being loaded" -foregroundcolor green

If it appears great if not please let me know.

Comment: Hello,

New plan. Edit the $profile that you create and add the line 

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

Now instead of using the SharePoint management shell just use the standard PowerShell command window.

You will still have the SharePoint functionality and the drive should be c: rather than u:

Comment: It didn't work.  I've added an image to the post.  Thank you.